# Can a Lightsail web site access mysql data bases that are not on the aws platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a lightsail web site that stores info in a mysql DB hosted by my lightsail instance (LAMP).  But, I need my site to be able to insert data into a mysql database that is not hosted in lightsail.  I have data on my site that needs to be sent to a database at each of my pizza stores.  Is this possible with lightsail?  If so, can you point me in the right direction as I don't seem to be able to connect to my remote databases.

I don't need help with the PHP programming to do this, just help in connecting to the remote databases.

Thanks for any help you can give me?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.  I did not have the connection string formated correctly.